# Downloading data from google cloud platform app via appcfg.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Ever since migrating from the old app engine to google cloud platform, I've had some trouble downloading data from my app using appcfg.py. Here is the command that I enter:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file='directory/exp/bulkloader.yaml' --filename=rawdata.csv --kind=DataObject --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

Here is the output:

```
08:12 AM Downloading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20160608.081204
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20160608.081204.sql3
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-results-20160608.081204.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Downloading kinds ['DataObject']................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down.........
[ERROR   ] [WorkerThread-9] WorkerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 172, in WorkOnItems
status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 750, in PerformWork
transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1156, in _TransferItem
self, retry_parallel=self.first)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1447, in GetEntities
results = self._QueryForPbs(query)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1404, in _QueryForPbs
result_pb)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 95, in MakeSyncCall
return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 329, in MakeSyncCall
rpc.CheckSuccess()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
self.request, self.response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 286, in MakeSyncCall
handler(request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 318, in _Dynamic_RunQuery
'datastore_v3', 'RunQuery', query, query_result)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 201, in MakeSyncCall
self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 228, in _MakeRealSyncCall
response_pb.ParseFromString(encoded_response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 140, in ParseFromString
self.MergeFromString(s)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 152, in MergeFromString
self.MergePartialFromString(s)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 168, in MergePartialFromString
self.TryMerge(d)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_pb.py", line 770, in TryMerge
d.skipData(tt)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 677, in skipData
raise ProtocolBufferDecodeError, "corrupted"
ProtocolBufferDecodeError: corrupted
[ERROR   ] [WorkerThread-4] WorkerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 172, in WorkOnItems
status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 750, in PerformWork
transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1156, in _TransferItem
self, retry_parallel=self.first)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1447, in GetEntities
results = self._QueryForPbs(query)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1404, in _QueryForPbs
result_pb)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 95, in MakeSyncCall
return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 329, in MakeSyncCall
rpc.CheckSuccess()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
self.request, self.response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 286, in MakeSyncCall
handler(request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 318, in _Dynamic_RunQuery
'datastore_v3', 'RunQuery', query, query_result)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 201, in MakeSyncCall
self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 228, in _MakeRealSyncCall
response_pb.ParseFromString(encoded_response)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 140, in ParseFromString
self.MergeFromString(s)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 152, in MergeFromString
self.MergePartialFromString(s)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 168, in MergePartialFromString
self.TryMerge(d)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_pb.py", line 770, in TryMerge
d.skipData(tt)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 673, in skipData
raise ProtocolBufferDecodeError, "corrupted"
ProtocolBufferDecodeError: corrupted
.[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-4: corrupted
[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-5: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Too many auth attempts.
[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-9: corrupted

[INFO    ] Have 3095 entities, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 3095 entities (15070507 bytes) transferred in 391.3 seconds
```

I'm quite the noob at this, so it may be a pretty easy fix. Any thoughts on how to fix this issue would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: Do you get the error consistently?  It seems like the sort of thing that could be caused by a network blip.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, consistently. I also am getting it on more than one project, and on more than one computer (and more than one network).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just faced the same issue. It seems this has to do with threading.

I've been able to solve it by setting specifically the number of threads to 1 in appcfg command line:

```
appcfg.py download_data -A APP-ID --url=http://APP-ID.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=data.db --num_threads=1
```

It does take longer to download data but it succeeded with no errors.